# What kind of data structure is most efficient for a DAG given no node class?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a directed acyclic graph I'm trying to implement but I'm not sure what structure I can use. I keep believing that a tree or adjacency list would be viable but I am not given nodes to work with.

So in this case I tried to implement it using a 2d array, storing the priorities, in degrees and out degrees. However, I'm having problems figuring out how to insert an edge between two vertices and how I can check if a vertice is another vertice's parent in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you're "storing the priorities, in degrees and out degrees", it suggests you don't quite grok adjacency matrices. For an adjacency matrix M, vertices correspond to indices, and edges from *v* to *u* correspond to an entry in the matrix at M<sub>vu</sub> (i.e. M<sub>vu</sub> is the number of edges from *v* to *u*). The out-degree of a vertex *v* is ΣM<sub>*v</sub>; the in-degree is ΣM<sub>v*</sub>. If the matrix is in row-major order (M<sub>row, col</sub>), these correspond to the column and row sums, respectively.

"Priority" isn't a vertex property in plain DAGs. If you have priorities associated with the vertices, your graph class should contain another data structure mapping vertices to priorities (probably a vector, since vertices are usually numbered consecutively). Better still, have two graph classes: a `DAG` class, and a child `PriorityDAG` class that adds a priority property for nodes:

```
class DAG {
public:
    typedef int Vertex;
    ...
};

class PriorityDAG : public DAG {
public:
    using DAG::Vertex;
    typedef int Priority;

    Priority priority(Vertex vertex);

protected:
    std::vector<Priority> priorities;
    ...
};
```

If you're ever going to have other types of graphs (undirected, cyclic), you can make a `Graph` class to be the parent of `DAG`.

Thus, to insert an edge, increment the value M<sub>vu</sub>. If *v* is a parent of *u*, then there is an edge from *v* to *u*, so M<sub>vu</sub> > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use also a bidirectional hash table to map your node identifiers to actual "Node" objects and back, and then use any standard representation of your choice. E.g. if your nodes are actually strings, and you can't store any linked lists "directly" into the strings, have a bidirectional hash table string -> Node -> string and then put the actual datastructures to the Node class.